# Azure options for building a database-backed website?

Tags: azure, post, browser, server, get

Is Azure appropriate for building an entire database-backed website, with custom tables on the backend, and custom pages, forms, and CSS on the frontend?

Like any database-backed website, there should be facility for backend logic in response to client-browser GET & POST requests.

Which Azure resources are appropriate? Logic Apps?

Comment: what do you mean by entire database-backed website? PaaS databases?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio if by PaaS, you mean a web-based application development platform, then no. I just mean a "dynamic" website, with a database on the backend.

Comment: PaaS is platform as a service, which means you won't manage any virtual machine ...just your app

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Ok, it was unclear whether you were talking about what i want to build VS. which tools to use to build it. When i said "entire database-backed website", that's what i want to build. When you mentioned PaaS, i guess you meant that's a tool use to build my website? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing an [answer i received on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21560b20-1c0f-488f-9895-6abbaf18f03c/appropriate-for-entire-website?forum=azurelogicapps). (not sure yet if i will mark this one as best answer):

While is it possible, you have better options to consider.

If you are building a JS-powered frontend (using Angular/React), you could host the static assets directly on blob storage and expose it as a [static website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website). The doc also covers how you could add a CDN to it for faster delivery to your customers.

The backend could be built entirely using [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). If you are using Table Storage or CosmosDB, there are bindings available that you could use and simplify the code that you would have to manage.

If you have background workflows (like batch jobs) that you have to run, then Logic Apps are indeed a good option. For complex use cases, [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) might be a better fit though.

Comment: By "database backed", i mean a dynamic, not static, site.

Comment: They replied: "Even if the assets (JS, CSS, HTML, etc.) are served as static files, your JS code could still make requests to your API (could be functions) that return dynamic content from your database (or any data source).

Angular/React (and even Vue.JS) are standard choices these days for JS-powered web apps that you could look into."